# How to run test case from all modules?

Tags: go

Below is the code structure of workspace:

```
test$ ls -lR
.:
total 1824
drwxrwxr-x 3 user user    4096 Nov  8 10:55 cmd
drwxrwxr-x 2 user user    4096 Nov  8 11:07 compute
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user      40 Nov  8 10:54 go.work
-rwxrwxr-x 1 user user 1846984 Nov  8 11:04 main
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user     183 Nov  8 11:05 Makefile
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user      13 Nov  8 08:59 Readme.md

./cmd:
total 4
drwxrwxr-x 2 user user 4096 Nov  8 10:49 user

./cmd/user:
total 8
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user  49 Nov  8 10:49 go.mod
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user 132 Nov  8 10:57 main.go

./compute:
total 16
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user 339 Nov  8 09:58 fib.go
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user 204 Nov  8 11:10 fib_test.go
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user 239 Nov  8 11:07 go.mod
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user 881 Nov  8 11:07 go.sum
test$ 
test$ pwd
/home/user/git/test
test$  go version
go version go1.20.2 linux/amd64
```

---

Every testcase file has build tag:

```
//go:build unit
// +build unit
```

---

To run test cases in `./compute`, I had to mention path of the module, as shown below:

```
test$ make test
go test -v -race -tags=unit -cover ./compute
=== RUN   TestZeroeth
--- PASS: TestZeroeth (0.00s)
PASS
        github.com/whatever/test/compute coverage: 100.0% of statements
ok      github.com/whatever/test/compute (cached)        coverage: 100.0% of statements
test$
```

---

How to run test cases from multiple modules? with single command...

Without go workspace, we were using, `test$ go test -tags=unit -cover ./...` previously

Comment: modules are separate entities. Use a script, makefile, etc. to run multiple commands in multiple directories.

Comment: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/51756